Dynamic importing give issue in react vite
Hi I am wokring on app using react-vite so my requirement is to import the content dynamically so in my view.tsx I am using
const loadRemoteContent = async (id: string) => {
  try {
    console.log("remoteApp", `remoteApp/${id}Content`); // remoteApp remoteApp/demo1Content
    const module = await import(`remoteApp/${id}Content`);
    return module;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error loading remote content:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to load remote content');
  }
};

but it gives error while loading

Error loading remote content: TypeError: Failed to resolve module
specifier 'remoteApp/demo1Content'
at loadRemoteContent (view.tsx?t=1718293025034:24:50)
at view.tsx?t=1718293025034:42:13

Please guide me how to resolve this because it works fine when I load it statically like
const module = await import('remoteApp/demo1Content');

Please help me solving this. Thanks in advance!

Could you try to include 'Content' string as your id part? And also .ts, .js, .tsx, '.jsx' extensions as well. I believe this is some limitation of how vite search the package: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import.
Or you may try glob import if the files is statically available in the build time
